# Hyperparameter data types and scales not being validated

Tags: python-3.x, hyperparameters, google-cloud-vertex-ai, spacy-3

On past week, I was implementing some code to [tune hyperparameters on a spaCy model, using Vertex AI](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/11126#discussioncomment-3191163). From that experience, I have several questions, but since they might no be directly related to each other, I decided to open one case per each question.

In this case, I would like to understand what is exactly going on, when I set the following hyperparameters, in some HP tuning job:

[image: hyperparameters]

Notice **both examples have been purposedly written 'wrongly' to trigger an error but 'eerily', they don't** (UPDATE: at least with my current understanding of the docs). I have the sensation that *"Vertex AI does not make any validation of the inserted values, they just run whatever you write, and trigger an error only if the values don't actually make ANY sense"*. Allow me to insert a couple of comments on each example:

- `dropout`: This variable should be *"scaled linearly between 0 and 1"* ... However what I can see in the HP tuning jobs, are values *"scaled linearly between 0.1 and 0.3, and nothing in the interval 0.3 to 0.5"*. Now this reasoning is a bit naive, as I am not 100% sure if [this algorithm](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/ai-machine-learning/hyperparameter-tuning-cloud-machine-learning-engine-using-bayesian-optimization) had to do in the values selection, or *"Google Console understood I only had the interval [0.1,0.3] to choose values from"*. (UPDATE) Plus, how can a variable be "discrete and linear" at the same time?
- `batch_size`: I think I know what's going on with this one, I just want to confirm: 3 categorical values ("500", "1000" & "2000") are being selected "as they are", since they have a SHP of "UNESPECIFIED".

(*) Notice both the HP names, as well as their values, were just "examples on the spot", they don't intend to be "good starting points". HP tuning initial values selection is NOT the point of this query.

Thank you.

Comment: It might be better to open a [public issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) under Vertex AI to report this behavior.

Comment: Hello @RiccoD, thanks for the suggestion. Since the company where I collaborate has Google Official Support enabled, I have also opened a case there (basically a copy & paste of this post); the case is currently under revision. If they reply, I will make sure to share their comments in this case also.

Comment: @DavidEspinosa: Can you paste the code you're using to call Vertex? In particular, I'm not sure what "Experimental values" means or why these examples are "wrong".

Comment: Hello @tskuzzy. Unfortunately, I cannot share the whole code related to the hyperparameter tuning, as it is propietary. When I say "Experimental", I mean "they're part of an experiment" (as any other HP tuning job). When I say "wrong", I mean "according to Google docs, with those values I should get an error, but I don't". As to "why they're 'wrong', please refer to the comments. As for the values, I set the HP variable values using Console, which is not that different from the table shown in my original post. With all that said, let me know if I can help you somehow with this issue.

Comment: @DavidEspinosa: You need to share the [ParameterSpec](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/training/hyperparameter-tuning-overview#data-types), otherwise we can't tell whether the hyperparameters ([0.1, 0.3, 0.5] and [500, 1000, 2000]) are wrong. Based on your description, there isn't anything out of the ordinary here since they satisfy the data type and scale parameter that you posted.

Comment: Hello @tskuzzy, I did not set the HP job via code, but via console. I have inserted the values I used. I also realized about some errors in my original post, which have been included. Thank you.

Comment: @DavidEspinosa: I believe the ScaleType is ignored if the type is not DoubleValueSpec or IntegerValueSpec. But let me get back to you on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the type is Categorical, then the scale type is irrelevant and ignored. If the type is DoubleValueSpec, IntegerValueSpec, or DiscreteValueSpec, then the scale type will govern which values are picked more often.

Regarding how a variable can be both Discrete and have a scale: Discrete variables are still numeric in nature. For example, if the discrete values are `[1, 10, 100]`, the ScaleType will determine whether the optimization algorithm considers "distance" between 1 and 10 versus 10 and 100 the same (if logarithmic) or smaller (if linear).

Comment: I'm OK with the Categorical explanation. Regarding `dropout` (Values=[0.1,0.3,0.5]; Scaling=Lineal), how does "scale type will govern which values are picked more often" explain what's going on here? (i.e., Only the range [0.1,0.3] seems to be picked linearly)? Regarding `dropout` too, do you think "Bayesian Optimization" has to do wiht the behavior seen here?

Comment: For dropout, you should probably be using DoubleValueSpec to specify a range from [0.1, 0.5] instead of discrete values if you want values across that range. I'm not sure why 0.5 wouldn't be picked in the DiscreteValueSpec you provided though. Maybe there weren't enough trials or something. If you want further debugging on the issue, please file a ticket through https://cloud.google.com/support-hub

Comment: Like I mentioned in my original post, I **intentionally** picked "wrong" hyperparameter types, just to "demonstrate" the seeming "missing validation" of them. I am aware that DoubleValueSpec would be a better choice for `dropout` and yet, that does not quite explain why Vertex AI Hyperparameter Tuning ("HPT"), "allows a wrong value". I think that Vertex AI HPT in general does not do this validation at all, but relies on the developer's knowledge, to set the best hyperparameter values / types / scaling. Do you think so?

Comment: PS.: I have already opened a ticket but funnily enough, Google Support has addressed me to this Stack Overflow case... (Reference: Support Case # 40329033, Project # 791864177482). FYI.

Comment: I see. Yes it seems that there is currently no validation that the ScaleType is set appropriately for CategoricalValueSpec. I also added some more detail to the answer regarding the ScaleType and how it behaves with discrete variables. Hope that answers your question.

Comment: If you add the "currently no validation for a matching ScalyType and CategoricalValueSpec is made from Vertex AI Hyperparameter Tuning side" part to your answer, I think I can accept it. Of course, the previous idea relies entirely on being true (whose confirmation, I'd appreciate from your side). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After some rehearsals (and with the helpful insights of @tskuzzy, as well as GCP Support), I have got to the following conclusions:

- Vertex AI Hyperparameter tuning selection DOES NOT do any "value validation" for you: The designer must carefully choose the Values, Types (and Scaling, if it is a numerical value).
- Regarding the [hyperparameter data type](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/training/hyperparameter-tuning-overview#data-types):

  - For `CategoricalValueSpec` type, whatever value you set will be considered as a string by default by Vertex IA, but "the last word" will be kept by how you structured your code (when using `argparse` library).
  - For `DoubleValueSpec` and `IntegerValueSpec` type, only the first two values will be noticed: if you set your values to be [0,4,8,...], only [0,4] is considered and the rest are discarded. If for some reason you set only one value, this value becomes a constant.
  - For `discreteValues` type, you must sort the variables yourself (i.e., set [0,4,8] and not [0,8,4]).
- Regarding [scale hyperparameters](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/training/hyperparameter-tuning-overview#scale_hyperparameters):

  - Use them preferably for `DoubleValueSpec` and `IntegerValueSpec` alone (Remember: nothing prevents you to use them for other types, but results can get unstable during the hyperparameter tuning).
  - Using `UNIT_LINEAR_SCALE`, `UNIT_LOG_SCALE` or `UNIT_REVERSE_LOG_SCALE` scale hyperparameters, for a `discreteValues` or a `CategoricalValueSpec` type variable (where values are numbers), will forcefully turn your variable type into `DoubleValueSpec` (!)
  - Using `UNIT_LINEAR_SCALE`, `UNIT_LOG_SCALE` or `UNIT_REVERSE_LOG_SCALE` scale hyperparameters, for a `CategoricalValueSpec` type variable, ***might*** pop up an error, if the values are a list of strings (the error gets more likely triggered by the code you built using `argparse` instead of Vertex AI).

So, be wary when setting up your variables in Vertex AI Hyperparameter tuning